# Why do sources online tend to call `cmake .. && make` instead of `cmake .. && cmake --build build --target install`

Tags: cmake

Very often in projects which use CMake, you'll see the following instructions

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make install
```

Or a variant

CMake is a build automation tool and works with a number of builders. So the steps above seemed strange to me because

1. It implies Linux (or at least access to `mkdir` and `cd`
2. It changes your `$PWD` which in my opinion shouldn't matter for a build
3. It hard codes `make`

In my personal code, I tend to instead call

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<wherever_I_want_to_install>  # -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is optional
cmake --build build --target install
# ... or ...
cmake --build build
cmake --install build --prefix=<wherever_I_want_to_install>
```

1. No hard-coded `make`. 100% CMake commands
2. No change in `$PWD`
3. Less OS-specific details

It's rarer but if I need compiler-specific options or other customizations, I pass them via command-line using `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and try to keep the CMakeLists.txt as builder-agnostic as possible.

Are there <del>objective differences</del> (edit: for clarity: objective **pros / cons**) between these approaches. If so, what are they? And if there isn't any meaningful differences between the two approaches, why is the `make install` option so frequent?

Comment: `Are there objective differences between these approaches` You just listed them... `No change in $PWD` `ctest --test-dir <dir>` was _finally_ added.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I didn't link to any external webpage

Comment: Edited my question to be more specifically whether my suggested alternative has cons that the other doesn't have or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do sources online tend to call `cmake .. && make` instead of `cmake .. && cmake --build build --target install`

I believe there are these reasons:

- people are more familiar with `make`, so they tend to use what they are familiar with
- `cmake --build` didn't exist at that time
- the author doesn't know that `cmake --build` exists, because of the reason above